# Wi-Fi Captive Portal's successfully authenticated page is closed automatically in Nokia (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, nokia

We are providing free, ads-supported Wi-Fi using Captive Portal: When an user selects the Wi-Fi, the first page is automatically pop up, she inputs a provided user/pass (e.g., "guest"/"guest") to log in. Finally, the 2nd page is also automatically pop up to "tell" that the authentication is successfully done.

However, in Nokia Lumia 1320 (Windows Phone 8.1) the 2nd page has been showing for a very short time then disappeared. While, in iOS, Android and previous version before Windows Phone 8.1, it does not (keep showing until one presses "Done" button to manually close it).

Why it is a problem for us? Because the 2nd page is normally showing various advertising (ads) campaigns. If it disappears too soon, there is no time for users to do interact with the ads.

My question is why? And how to fix it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try allowing access to the  www.msftncsi.com as a whitelist so the MS captive portal check gets disabled ?

regards,
Sukhdeep